# Doc2Vec: infer most similar vector from ConcatenatedDocvecs

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am generating a Doc2Vec embedding of a Pandas DataFrame by following the guidance provided [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-IMDB.ipynb)

```
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
from gensim.test.test_doc2vec import ConcatenatedDoc2Vec
import gensim.models.doc2vec
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cube_embedded =  # pandas cube
# convert the cube to documents
alldocs = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(cube_embedded.values.tolist())]

# train models
simple_models = [
    # PV-DBOW plain
    Doc2Vec(dm=0, vector_size=100, negative=5, hs=0, min_count=2, sample=0, epochs=20, workers=cores),
    # PV-DM w/ default averaging; a higher starting alpha may improve CBOW/PV-DM modes
    Doc2Vec(dm=1, vector_size=100, window=10, negative=5, hs=0, min_count=2, sample=0, epochs=20, workers=cores, alpha=0.05, comment='alpha=0.05'),
    # PV-DM w/ concatenation - big, slow, experimental mode window=5 (both sides) approximates paper's apparent 10-word total window size
    Doc2Vec(dm=1, dm_concat=1, vector_size=100, window=5, negative=5, hs=0, min_count=2, sample=0, epochs=20, workers=cores),
]

for d2v_model in simple_models:
    d2v_model.build_vocab(alldocs)
    d2v_model.train(alldocs, total_examples=d2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=d2v_model.epochs)

models_by_name = OrderedDict((str(d2v_model), d2v_model) for d2v_model in simple_models)
models_by_name['dbow+dmm'] = ConcatenatedDoc2Vec([simple_models[0], simple_models[1]])
models_by_name['dbow+dmc'] = ConcatenatedDoc2Vec([simple_models[0], simple_models[2]])
```

Given a document vector V, if I try to infer the most similar documents to the document vector V from a ConcatenatedDocvecs model, I get the following error:

```
V = np.random.rand(200)
models_by_name['dbow+dmc'].docvecs.most_similar([V])

AttributeError: 'ConcatenatedDocvecs' object has no attribute 'most_similar'
```

Of course, I cannot use the simple models to infer similar documents as the produced vector embeddings have size 100 (and not 200 as the concatenated vectors do).

How can I get the list of most similar documents to a document vector from a ConcatenatedDocvecs model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConcatenatedDocvecs` is a simple utility wrapper class that lets you access the concatenation of a tag's vectors in multiple underlying `Doc2Vec` models. It exists to make it a little easier to reproduce some of the analysis in the original 'ParagraphVector' paper.

It doesn't reproduce all the functionality of a `Doc2Vec` model (or set of keyed-vectors), so can't directly hep you with the `most_similar()` you want to perform.

You could instead do a most-similar operation within each of the constituent models, then combine the two similarity measures (per neighbor) – such as by averaging them – to get a usable similarity-like value for the combined model (and then re-sort on that). I suspect, but am not sure, such a value from the two 100d models would behave very much like a a true cosine-similarity from the concatenated 200d model.

Alternatively, instead of using `ConcatenatedDoc2Vec` wrapper class (which only creates and returns the concatenated 200d vectors when requested), you could look at the various `KeyedVectors` class in gensim, and use (or adapt) one to be filled with all the concatenated 200d vectors from the two constituent models. Then, its `most_similar()` would work.